# Date Filter (XlDynamicFilterCriteria) with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a column with 2 criteria. I need all data from this month and last month.

what is working: one single criteria, the Operator is "xlFilterDynamic"

```
Sub filtertest()
    Dim LastMonth As XlDynamicFilterCriteria
    LastMonth = xlFilterLastMonth
    
    Dim ThisMonth As XlDynamicFilterCriteria
    ThisMonth = xlFilterThisMonth
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B92").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ThisMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

What is not working: two criteria, the Operator is still "xlFilterDynamic", but maybe that's not correct. I put the two criteria into an array. I receive an error 1004.

```
Sub filtertest_withArray()

    Dim LastMonth As XlDynamicFilterCriteria
    LastMonth = xlFilterLastMonth
    
    Dim ThisMonth As XlDynamicFilterCriteria
    ThisMonth = xlFilterThisMonth
    
    Dim arrCriteria() As Variant
    ReDim arrCriteria(0 To 1)
    arrCriteria(0) = LastMonth
    arrCriteria(1) = ThisMonth
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B92").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arrCriteria(), Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
End Sub
```

But if I set the Operator to "xlFilterValues" it runs through without an error, but all datasets are filtered out.

[image]

edit:
When I set the filter to this, it won't work either. It will just filter the dates from last month.

```
Criteria1:=LastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic, Criteria2:=ThisMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FilterLastAndCurrentMonths()
    Dim lastDayOfCurrentMonth As Variant
    Dim lastDayOfLastMonth As Variant
    
    With Application
        lastDayOfCurrentMonth = Format(.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        lastDayOfLastMonth = Format(.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Range("$D$3:$D$50").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, lastDayOfLastMonth, 1, lastDayOfCurrentMonth)
        
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: not working for me. somehow I face issues with the date format.

Comment: I formatted the date has you have in your post and it works! See the picture I posted now, tell me your issues with dates. Select one of your dates and post a picture like mine.

Comment: I receive an err.number 1004. my date is formatted asme as yours. dd.mm.yyyy
I don't even understand this array you are using...

Comment: In each line the error appears? The array results from recording a macro! Star recording a macro, then clear the filters, then select only the last and current month and finaaly stop the macro. You'll get the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need dynamic criteria to achieve what you are (were) seeking to achieve.

Searching between two date criteria works in below example using AND operator.

```
'Establish criteria bounds
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date
startDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1)
endDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)

'Clear filter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B92").AutoFilter Field:=1

'Set Filter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B92").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endDate
```

A great way to play around with table filtering is to record a macro, set filters as you'd like manually, and then review the recorded code.